# Confirm solution to chapter 2, Problem 18 in Rudin's book: principals of mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Is there a non-empty perfect set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$ which contains no rational numbers?

My effort:

Yes, there is.

We take $E_0 \colon = [\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$. Then $E_0$ is non-empty, closed, and bounded (and hence compact). Let $q_1$ be a rational number in $E_0$, Then $q_1$ is in the interior of $E_0$.

Now let $N_1$ be a neighborhood of $q_1$ such that $N_1 \subset E_0$. Let $E_1 \colon= E_0 - N_1$. Then $q_1 \not\in E_1$. But $E_1$ is non-empty. Also $E_1 \subset E_0$. And, of course, $E_1$ is closed and bounded (and hence compact). Let $q_2$ be a rational number in $E_1$. Then $q_2 \neq q_1$, furthermore, $q_2$ is in the interior of $E_1$.

So let $N_2$ be a neighborhood of $q_2$ such that $N_2 \subset E_1$. Let $E_2 \colon= E_1 - N_2$. Then $q_2 \not\in E_2$. But $E_2$ is non-empty, closed, and bounded (and therefore compact). Also we have $E_2 \subset E_1 \subset E_0$. Let $q_3$ be a rational number in $E_2$. Then $q_3 \neq q_1$ and $q_3 \neq q_2$. Furthermore, $q_3$ lies in the interior of $E_2$.

Continuing in this manner, assume $E_n$ has been chosen such that $E_n$ is non-empty, closed, and bounded (and hence compact) and such that $E_n \subset E_{n-1}$ and $q_n \notin E_n$. Let $q_{n+1}$ be a rational number in $E_n$. Then $q_n \neq q_i$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, and $q_{n+1}$ is in the interior of $E_n$.

So let $N_{n+1}$ be a neighborhood of $q_{n+1}$ such that $N_{n+1} \subset E_n$. Let $E_{n+1} \colon= E_n - N_{n+1}$. Then $q_{n+1} \not\in E_{n+1}$, but $E_{n+1}$ is non-empty, closed, and bounded (and therefore compact). Also, $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$.

Using induction, we have thus constructed a sequence $\{E_n\}$, $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ of non-empty closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$ and $q_n \not\in E_n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Let $E \colon= \cap_{n=0}^\infty E_n$. Then evidently $E$ is closed and $q_n \not\in E$ for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Now is this $E$ our desired perfect set?

If $p \in E$, then $p \in E_n$ for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. How to show that $p$ is a limit point of $E$?

If not, then what is the solution to the original problem?

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/office/b-KV1swGce/rudin_ch_2.html

Comment: You need to make sure you have used all the rationals up as centers of removed intervals, or they were removed in an open interval before that. Also you need to make sure there aren't any open intervals left over afterwards.

Comment: My feeling is that, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you will have an empty set for result. There is no point in $\mathbb{R}$ that is not in the neighborhood of a rational.

Comment: What's the definition of perfect?

Comment: @orace Thats false.